# Manage small amount if data, in balanced server iis

Tags: .net, json, database, iis, load-balancing

I need to store/retrieve and modify a very small amount of data, at the moment this data are write on 2/3 json file and read from my application deployed on 4 iis server, so every server as a copy of this file.
I want to make a simple interface to change this data, and eventually delete my 4 copies.
i can't decide how to do this, i will prefear to not use database like sql or my sql, is a very small amount of data and using a db will be excessive imho, i'll like to find a simple solution maybe using the same json but storing that file outside my application.

Ty all

Comment: Would you mind clarifying the question with what actual data is stored inside your configuration files? Furthermore how often do you intent to change the configuration? Is the configuration computer dependant or always the same? How do you intent to change this data? Do you have any shared storage between the servers? Do the servers belong together or are they actually independent from one another?

Comment: data will be modified 2 times @ week and data contained is not related to the pc, are configuration based on some table of a database that i can not touch.. for example i got a table with a list of city, in my file i have some bool to configure for some of the city in the  contained in the database. i can find a way to share some storage between the server, but if there are any other possibility i prefear to not use shared storage